# How to open link in app when we tap the notification

Tags: android, onesignal

I recently developed native android app for my wordpress blog. I'm using OneSignal push notification service in the project. Also, I'm able to receive notifications. The problem is whenever i get notifications on the device and I tap it, it opens the browser instead of the app.
Here's the snippet of main Activity Java code.

```
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
    import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, HomeFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    private AdView mAdView;
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new NotificationHandler())
                .init();
         Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
         setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

         navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
         onNavigationItemSelected(navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0));


     }
```

Here's the class `NotificationHandler`

```
package com.savvydroid.savvydroid;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.onesignal.OSNotificationAction;
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationOpenResult;
import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

+import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
+ * Created by geeth on 12/30/2017.
 */
class NotificationHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
    public Context mcontext;
    @Override
    public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
        OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
        JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;
        String customKey;

        if (data != null) {
            customKey = data.optString("customkey", null);
            if (customKey != null)
                Log.i("OneSignalExample", "customkey set with value: " + customKey);
        }

        if (actionType == OSNotificationAction.ActionType.ActionTaken)
            Log.i("OneSignalExample", "Button pressed with id: " + result.action.actionID);

        Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Add a comment to this line
        mcontext.startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Someone please help, i need to finish this project at the earliest.

Answer (score 2):

you should use PendingIntent.

you can see example in [journaldev](https://www.journaldev.com/10463/android-notification-pendingintent)